# Cannot import Kal.h file in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, kal

I'm trying to import the `kal library` into my project.
I have added the `framework` to my project and did the imports. I think the problem is with my `build settings.`

I've setted them up like this.

```
${SOURCE_ROOT}/Classes/External
```

And here is a screenshot where the Kal source is situated

[image]

And here is a screenshot of my build settings.

[image]
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: There seems to be a space in the path which can be the issue. If I am reading it correct there is a space in `../Sanmax dokter/..` portion of the path

Comment: That seems to be the issue ! thx !